# Problems on probability measure notations for expectation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

I find it very tough to understand Resnick notation for expectation in Probability Path chapter 5 (for which I am not given any kind of explanation nor definition, which is strange), here it is:
$$E(X)=\int_\Omega XdP=\int_\Omega X(\omega)P(d\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R}xF(dx) $$

Although I also found some similar questions, I still can't get what actually means' $dP, P(d\omega), F(dx)$', and how they are the same (under differents measure of course). In particular, what is the event $[X\in dx]$ ?

As always, many thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all standard notations for the same thing, found in many textbooks.
Like all notations, they are conventional.  Section 5.2 of Resnick's book is devoted to defining $E(X)$; the first two equations you mention are given as definitions on page 119. The third equation is covered by the contents of section 5.5; see especially p.138.

Your question about the meaning of the event $[X\in dx]$ is more-or-less equivalent to asking "what is the number $dx$?", when confronted with an expression like  $\int f(x)dx$ in a calculus textbook.  If you are satisfied with an answer like "$\int f(x)dx$ is close to a Riemann sum $\sum f(x_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$" then you should be satisfied with an answer like "$\int X(\omega)P(d\omega)$ is approximated by a sum of form $\sum_{\Delta_i} X(\omega_i) P(X\in \Delta_i)$, where $\{\Delta_i\}$ is a partition of $\Omega$ for which $\omega_i\in\Delta_i,\forall i$."